# Issue reading from certain topics in Kafka in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a the following code I got from https://lgouellec.github.io/kafka-streams-dotnet/. I have a topic in kafka called topic1, where I write my messages. I get the stream and write it to another topic called testtopic. However when I try to read the content of testtopic using my consumer class, nothing happens. However when I pass another topic to my consumer class that is in Kafka, i am able to read the messages.

```
        public async Task GetKafkaStream()
        {
            await CreateTopicAsync("127.0.0.1:9092", "testtopic");

            var config = new StreamConfig<StringSerDes, StringSerDes>();
            config.ApplicationId = "test-app";
            config.BootstrapServers = "bootstrap.servers";

            StreamBuilder builder = new StreamBuilder();

            builder.Stream<string, string>("topic1")
           .To("testtopic");

            Topology t = builder.Build();
            KafkaStream stream = new KafkaStream(t, config);

            await stream.StartAsync();
            
            await Consumer("testtopic");
        }
```

My consumer class

```
            using (var consumer = new ConsumerBuilder<string, string>(
                configuration.AsEnumerable()).Build())
            {

                consumer.Subscribe("testtopic");
                try
                {
                    var cr = consumer.Consume();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    var message = ex.Message;
                }
                finally
                {
                    consumer.Close();
                }
            }
```

Comment: You can't await two things. The Streams app doesn't "stop" to be awaited. Kafka Streams is already a consumer, so not clear why you need another one (or an intermediate, duplicate topic)

Comment: In that case, would you be able to point me in the right direction on how I would be able to read all the contents (messages) of the "topic1"

Comment: That's exactly what `builder.Stream<string, string>("topic1")` does. You should be able to use `Peek`, `Print` or `ForeachAsync` operators to simply print the values... https://lgouellec.github.io/kafka-streams-dotnet/stateless-processors.html#peek

Comment: I did that but no values. Declare a dictionary to store values
**var foreachObserved = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();**
And then built the stream in the following way
         builder.Stream<string, string>("topic1")
               '.Foreach((k, v) => foreachObserved.Add(KeyValuePair.Create(k, v)));

Comment: That will run asyncronously, so if you've tried to print that list immeadiately after `Foreach`, then yeah, it'll be empty because the print happens before your topology actually finished. Print within the Foreach, or use Print operator, as shown in the documentation. If you want to accumulate data in some other datastucture, that is a separate problem